# Parse Cloud Code modifying variables

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm working on Microsoft Translator integration into Parse's Cloud Code. I can successfully obtain access token - example:

```
http%253a%252f%252fschemas.xmlsoap.org%252fws%252f2005%252f05%252fidentity%252fclaims%252fnameidentifier%3Dcapital-dev%26http%253a%252f%252fschemas.microsoft.com%252faccesscontrolservice%252f2010%252f07%252fclaims%252fidentityprovider%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%252f%26Audience%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fapi.microsofttranslator.com%26ExpiresOn%3D1446139162%26Issuer%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%252f%26HMACSHA256%3DRXDUXmSV1C%252bJPhtDFfe0obgUQ2ZOW1XtlzL00lE934E%253d
```

(very strange token, by the way, but works fine while debugging with Postman)

Later, when Im trying to send a translation request to

```
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate
```

with the same httpRequest I used for token:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url:    'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?appId=Bearer ' + request.params.token + '&to=en&text=' + request.params.text,
    success: function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error({
            token: request.params.token,
            error: error,
            url: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?appId=Bearer ' + request.params.token + '&to=en&text=' + request.params.text,
        });
    },
});
```

In error callback I got my token modified like this:

```
http%!a(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)schemas.xmlsoap.org%!f(MISSING)ws%!f(MISSING)2005%!f(MISSING)05%!f(MISSING)identity%!f(MISSING)claims%!f(MISSING)nameidentifier%!D(MISSING)capital-dev%!h(MISSING)ttp%!a(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)schemas.microsoft.com%!f(MISSING)accesscontrolservice%!f(MISSING)2010%!f(MISSING)07%!f(MISSING)claims%!f(MISSING)identityprovider%!D(MISSING)https%!a(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%!f(MISSING)%!A(MISSING)udience%!D(MISSING)http%!a(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)api.microsofttranslator.com%!E(MISSING)xpiresOn%!D(MISSING)1446139162%!I(MISSING)ssuer%!D(MISSING)https%!a(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)%!f(MISSING)datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%!f(MISSING)%!H(MISSING)MACSHA256%!D(MISSING)RXDUXmSV1C%!b(MISSING)JPhtDFfe0obgUQ2ZOW1XtlzL00lE934E%!d(MISSING)
```

I'm pretty stuck here...
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: console.log your token before you make the httpRequest.  Since you're getting the error call back, I'm going to guess it isn't correct prior to being put into the http request url.  print it out first thing in your cloud code method.  If it doesn't look right, print out exactly what you're adding as a parameter on the client side before you call the function, and make sure it looks right going in. Maybe however you're adding it in is trying to pull parameters into a string with that format.

Comment: Already tried to console.log my token before httpRequest - it's messed even out there.
On the client side - it looks fine, no unnecessary replacements. Looks like it's messing while passing through Parse.Cloud.run.

Comment: That's likely. Everything gets converted to JSON, and Parse' JSON parser probably does something funky with the string. Maybe you can store the string on an object and pass the object?